# Simple HTML code to display phone number and enable click to call on iOS

Tags: html

Does anyone know how to fix simple html code that displays a phone number but ipad and iphone will not display the numbers?

I did a bit of Google and I found out that the below meta tag makes the number to be displayed with a problem but now the click to call feature is not working. I want to click to call feature on iOS to be working as well.

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you have to target the number with a tel protocol

```
<a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us !</a>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response but I tried using a the tel protocol but it reverts back and the numbers are hidden on my iPhone and when I click on where the number is suppose to be then it shows the number. Doesn't show when I load my page initially.

Comment: as you can read by apple developer docs it have to work: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1